# Validating forms with JavaScript not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have two problems one I can't get the Regex (for email) I created to fire properly when I add it to my logic. It seems to make the field which was fine (by entering correct input) invalidate when I tab away...

The second problem is the select dropdown. I am not sure what is the best practice but I essentially would like the select dropdown to remain with the error messages until either the user has selected a proper state.

This is my code:

```
var ValidationChecker = (function validationHndlr() {
    'use strict';
    var doc = document;
    var form;
    var emailRegExp;
    var formElements;

    emailRegExp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    form = doc.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    formElements = form.elements;

    function addMultipleListeners(element, events, handler, useCapture, args) {
        if (!(events instanceof Array)) {
            throw 'addMultipleListeners: ' +
                'please supply an array of eventstrings ' +
                '(like ["click","mouseover"])';
        }
        //create a wrapper to be able to use additional arguments
        var handlerFn = function(e) {
            handler.apply(this, args && args instanceof Array ? args : []);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length - 1; i += 1) {
            element.addEventListener(events[i], handlerFn, useCapture);
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0, l = formElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        var elId = doc.getElementById(formElements[i].id);

        addMultipleListeners(elId, ['focus', 'blur', 'keyup'], function(e) {

            if ((formElements[i].value == '') || (formElements[i].value == null) || ((formElements[i].type == 'email') != emailRegExp) ) {
                formElements[i].classList.add('invalid-input');

                formElements[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
                formElements[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML = 'Not valid!';
            } 

        }, false);

        elId.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
            console.log('keyup working?');

            if ((formElements[i].value != '') && (formElements[i].value.length > 2)) {
                formElements[i].classList.remove('invalid-input');
                if (formElements[i].nextElementSibling.type !== 'submit') {
                  formElements[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }
        }, false);
    }
})();
```

Comment: A few notes. It doesn't make any sense to name your top-level function `validationHndlr` when you are going to have it self-invoke, unless you are going to call it again somewhere. Next, you understand that `var ValidationChecker` = (function validationHndlr() { ...` is going to set the variable `ValidationChecker` to the return value of the immediately invoked `validationHndlr` function, which doesn't seem to be returning a value. Also, by convention, functions names that begin with a capital letter indicate "constructor functions" that are meant to be instantiated with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Lastly, it seems like you are making the validation process much more involved than it has to be. Simply set up a callback function on the `<form>` element's `submit` event (and optionally on the elements `input` event to validate as data is entered or `blur` event to validate when a user leaves a field) and in that function (no self-invoking needed), do your validation. If validation fails cancel the event.

Comment: Hey thanks Scott...Originally I was going to make the `iife` into a module and it was to return some stuff from it and maybe make an API for it. I just hadn't gotten around to refactoring. Do you think you could give me an idea what you meant? My problem is I know there a lot of examples where one is using the `HTML5` inline/markup solutions for validation, which would circumvent the need for what I did. But I was asked to do it this way so there you have it...cheers!

Comment: Here's a scaled down version that shows the design. It is easy to build this out to your needs by just adding more validations that correctly set the `error` flag. https://jsfiddle.net/ws6begm3/4/

Comment: This looks so much cleaner and elegant! Thanks Scott!